Coordinates of text label after applying pos and offset parameters
Suppose I have the following plot:
plot(x=1, y=1, xlim=c(0,2), ylim=c(0,2))
text(x=1, y=1, lab="X", pos=3, offset=2)

How do I find the coordinates of the text label (lab="X") as the pos=3 and offset=2 parameters have modified the original position of x=1 and y=1?

The online doc for text reads, in part, "Accurate vertical centering needs character metric information on individual characters which is only available on some devices".  This makes me think that, if you need precise control over the positioning of text, you'd be better off using ggplot2, in which geom_text and allies allow positions to be specified in the same co-ordinates as the data.

Would the locator() function work for you?
